# Iterating through prefixes with Python

Tags: python, iterator

I have a hierarchical descriptor string that looks like `foo:bar:baz` where elements in the hierarchy are delimited by `:`, and I would like to iterate through the hierarchy levels. Is there an easy way to do this, something easier than this:

```
def hierarchy(s):
  segments = s.split(':')
  for i in range(len(segments)):
    prefix = ':'.join(segments[0:i+1])
    print prefix  
    # or do something else instead of prefix
```

Comment: Are you expecting the output `foo\nfoo:bar\nfoo:bar:baz\n`?

Comment: @delnan: yes, that looks right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
In [9]: [s[:m.start()] for m in re.finditer(':|$', s)]
Out[9]: ['foo', 'foo:bar', 'foo:bar:baz']
```

Answer (score 2):

A more readable solution:

```
def heirarchy(s):
    segments = s.split(':')
    result = []
    for segment in segments:
        result.append(segment)
        yield ':'.join(result)
```